# Memcached failing to set

Tags: php, memcached

Really weird one going on here. Recently, my memcached instance basically stopped setting keys and data. Like 99% of things just silently fail, when before, completely worked before.

Is there any way to fix this guys? I try setting a key named 'a' with the data 'test', and it still just fails and doesn't set.

It has been working for **months** but now suddenly not.

I've restarted the daemon, I've separated it into chunks instead of one big slab. All these things, and only a tiny amount of the data actually gets set.

I've setup a log with the command

```
memcached -d -m 3072 -l localhost -p 11211 -u nobody -v >> /var/log/memcached.log 2>&1
```

But it just remains empty. Anything wrong with the above?

Help guys! :)

Comment: Please elaborate on what have you changed and what diagnosing steps you did. For all we know now from your question, you might have just simply stopped the memcached daemon...

Comment: Apologies, I've elaborated in my main question.

Comment: Doesn't memcached have a log where to find messages like these?: http://old.nabble.com/an-error-found-in-memcache-log-td17645484.html

Comment: I've setup a log with the command "memcached -d -m 3072 -l localhost -p 11211 -u nobody -v >> /var/log/memcached.log 2>&1" But it just remains empty. Anything wrong with the above?

Comment: What version of memcached and what client?  memcached doesn't silently fail (unless you use the noreply options which is designed to hide errors).

Comment: 1.2.8 and the memcached php client.

Comment: There are a couple of PHP clients.  1.2.8 is a reasonably good version, but you'll want to make sure you're actually paying attention to return values.  It could very well be telling you something that you're doing wrong, or something wrong with internal state (much of which you can find by various stat commands).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming user **nobody** has write permissions to **/tmp**, try the following, noting the position of **2**

```
memcached -d -m 3072 -l localhost -p 11211 -u nobody -v 2>>/tmp/memcached.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not have broken anything.

Try telneting to the your memcache client from the machines that access memcache

Execute the following

```
$telnet [insert hostname] 11211

status

^]exit
```

The ^] is escape and then ] to quit the telnet connection.  You can set and get variables this way as well

I suspect, that the configuration may be broken, or the a firewall may have been put in place.